# Ignoring base properties in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I need to prevent mapping two fields ActionedBy and ActionedAt in the mapping profile. These are defined in a base class.

Is this the best way to do in c#. Is it repetition of code

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.AnnualCardTurnoverCustomRuleDefinition, 
                AnnualCardTurnoverCustomRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.ArrayComparisonRuleDefinition, 
                ArrayComparisonRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.MinimumAgeRuleDefinition, 
                MinimumAgeRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.MinimumTimeInBusinessRuleDefinition, 
                MinimumTimeInBusinessRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.NumericComparisonRuleDefinition, 
                NumericComparisonRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.RuleDefinition, 
                RuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.StringComparisonRuleDefinition, 
                StringComparisonRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.MccRuleDefinition, 
                MccRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.HighRiskCountryRuleDefinition, 
                HighRiskCountryRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
        CreateMap<OnboardingRules.Definition.CountyCourtJudgementRuleDefinition, 
                CountyCourtJudgementRuleDefinitionUpdatedMessage>()
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(sr => sr.ActionedBy, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Ignore()`  *prevents* mapping those fields

Comment: yes that is intentional. My question is it a repetition of code.

Comment: Both the properties are in the base class

Comment: That's not what the question asks though. It asks how to map, not how to ignore the properties. You can use the `[Ignore]` attribute on a property to ignore it. In this case it will be cleaner. Especially if those properties come from a base class

Comment: I don't think there's another way to do this. You can try and add a custom method to ignore those properties, but that's the only thing I can come up to. You can use extension methods too like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ignore+automapper
You still need to make the ignore in every map you do.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html